# How do i check a class is instantiated in JAVA

Tags: java, object, playframework

I'm trying to implement singleton concept in my play application. But before going into singleton concept can we find a class is instantiated, how many times it is instantiated

Comment: are you asking about how to implement a singleton?

Comment: @yi_H No. Sorry,I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to include a thread-safe static counter which is updated in your constructor:

```
public class CountedClass {
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public CountedClass() {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static int getInstanceCount() {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

Note that this will not show how many instances are *currently* alive, as it doesn't decrement the counter on destruction. You *could* override `finalize` to do that, but I wouldn't.

Also note that this is *not* the same thing as a singleton by a long chalk. The recommended ways of achieving a singleton are *either* using a single-value enum:

```
public enum Singleton
{
    INSTANCE;

    // Methods here
}
```

*or* like this:

```
public final class Singleton {
    // Thread-safe due to guarantees about initializers
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

You can use a nested type to achieve lazier initialization if you *really* need to, but I've rarely found that to be worth the complexity - the above patterns have always done me fine.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a singleton pattern is to make sure nobody will create an instance except for the Class itself. To do this we will make the constructor `private` so that nobody can instantiate it from outside. Then we will maintain a private variable which holds the instance of the class and a static method like `getInstance` which will return the instance. The full sample implementation can be found [here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-singleton-design-pattern). There are numerous implementation examples online too..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Singleton {

   private static Singleton instance = null;

   private Singleton() {
   }

   public static Singleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new Singleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.That was useful. I updated my question. Can we find how many times a class is instantiated in java.

Comment: Note that the code here isn't thread-safe. Two threads could both end up creating instances at the same time.

Comment: I came across this....Another way could be clone [link]http://www.kodejava.org/examples/12.html

Answer (score 0):

ake the instantiation protected:

```
    protected SingleClassName() {
       //your stuff here
    }
```

And what is publiclay accessible would be:

```
public static SingleClassNameGetInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new SingleClassName();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

You'll just need a private variable for it to check, something like:

```
private static instance = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thread-safe singletons**

- [Initialization on demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom)
- [Double-Checked Locking Pattern](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) (it works as of Java 5)